# Acumatica Mobile App - Customized but not in any customization project

Tags: mobile, acumatica

I have a mobile app that I did not write, but need to maintain.

Obviously, it has been customized. The main screen is completely changed:

MAIN MENU SCREEN SHOT FROM MOBILE APP IN ANDROID:
[image: Menu]

I need to know/change the screen that is being called when the mobile app user selects "Stock Items."

The problem is there is not ***ANY*** project in the customization projects list (Screen ID=SM204505) that has any modifications made to the mobile app. I mean NONE of them have ANY modifications. I looked in every project, and even in every tenant's projects. There is no mobile modifications listed anywhere.

The App\Mobile directory is empty except for the standard drilldown.ashx file.
[image: Mobile Folder]

I looked in the SQL Table: [MobileSiteMap] -- but not only do I not find the menu I am looking for, I find no menus available for anything other than CompanyID = 1. (This is company 2)

Where is it getting the customized menu, and how can I change what screen is getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go see if any of your GI is enabled for mobile app. By default they get added to the app main menu without further customization to the mobile app itself.

[image]

Comment: Yes, they are. So... if there is no customized menu, a defacto menu is created by all GIs that have the "expose to the Mobile Application" set?

Comment: No, even if you customized the app. These mobile enabled GIs will still appear.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as that was the issue here -- but this is a multipart question.... I will post a follow-up question, under a new topic.

Comment: If you get a chance, can you check my follow-up question Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145329/acumatica-mobile-app-not-using-default-screen-of-gi-navigation

Answer (score 0):

The mobile app is a UI layer for the screens in Acumatica.  It doesn't provide custom functionality to the business logic layer.  To see which screens added by default, create a new customization project.  Next, add a command to edit the sitemap.  On the preview pane, you will notice the folder structure &  screens that are added by default.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the response...The problem is when I do that, the folder structure and screens do not match what the user sees on the mobile app. It appears (I think) that no menu was modified or created, and the mobile app simply makes its own main menu based on which GIs have "Exposed to Mobile Data" checked. Is that possible?