# Acumatica Mobile App Not Using Default Screen of GI Navigation

Tags: c#, mobile, acumatica

I have the Stock Inventory GI as part of my mobile App (ScreenID: IN2025PL)

By default, it is set to navigate to the Stock Inventory screen when an inv item is selected. (ScreenID: IN202500). Everything is fine from the Web Application.

[image: IN2025PL]

The GI Is exposed to mobile, so it is shown in the mobile's menu.

[image: Mobile App Menu]

However, when I go to the GI, and then make a selection, I do not think it goes to IN202500. The reason is that the screen is read-only, and only a subset of the main screen's fields.

[image: Stock Item]

Also, none of my code is hit when I put a debugger on it.

I even added a CacheAttached event to see if it got hit, but no dice:

```
    protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<InventoryItem.stdCost> e) 
    {
      var onField =  e.BqlField.FullName;
    }
```

The breakpoint is never hit when I run this via the mobile App. Other screens work as expected. This screen works in the Web Application, as I said. But not in the Mobile App.

So, it seems somehow this is getting redirected to a different screen(?). But I cannot figure out which screen is being called. There is no customization project that modifies the Mobile application in any way.

How can I trace this and find out what screen is actually being called (so I can either modify what is being shown -- or better  yet, extend that screen so the Mobile app shows what I want it to.)

Comment: The fields you see in the mobile app are just the fields as per your GI design. Correct ? Its not loading the stock screen itself - IN202500. I think mobile app ignores the GI navigational parameters. Hence it's not firing the event. You have to explicitly design the stock screen if you want to interact with it.

Comment: I think you are partially right, but what I see seems more complex. I have other screens where I put a breakpoint, and it hits them just fine, and I don't have modified screens for them.

Comment: I changed the GI and made a different label, Interestingly, the new label was picked up in the WSDL when I generated it, but the mobile app still used the original label (which is what is defined in my Custom DAC) -- So it must be using something to create it's own screen, but I don't know where it's coming from